# Sign In in Magento Checkout doesn't translate

Tags: magento2, translate

[image]

**Have tried all combination:**

"Sign In", "Inloggen"
" Sign In ", "Inloggen"
"sign in","Inloggen"
" sign in ", "Inloggen"

But it resists translating this.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank You
Alain

Comment: Have you tried online translation?
And what does it look like ?

Comment: where and how you put the code?

Comment: Yes, but this 1 is not allowed to translate, I put it in i18n but other things it does translate expect this 1 is resisting to translate